# Best ways to stream live video to a webpage using Python/C++/Java

Tags: java, c++, python, streaming

I want to read in a live video stream, like RTSP, run some basic processing on it, and display it on a website.  What are some good ways to do this?  I have used OpenCV for Python before but found it to be a hassle.  I am also familiar with Java and C++ if there are better libraries available.  I haven't done a lot of web development before either.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of live video source that you mean? If you don't intend to do this code-wise, you can use the free VLC Player to act as a streaming service in between any kind of media stream source (file, network, capture device, disc) and your web video client.

But, if you intend to do this code-wise, you can you VLCJ library. Other options can be Xuggler or FMJ.

Comment: @ee: Regarding your pending edit, remember that when you change another user's response you are putting words in their mouth.  Edit to fix mechanical problems like formatting but please do not substantially change another user's answer. Comments are preferred for that.

Comment: actually both `eee` and `ee.` are my unregistered accounts on different browsers

Comment: Ah, well, that's a different story. :-)  When reviewing suggested edits one of the most common cases is people editing other folks responses inappropriately. Since it's impossible to tell the two accounts are the same person you may occasionally get an edit rejected for this reason.  Can't be helped but it does allow you to remain unregistered so a bit of a mixed bag there.